# Regex to capture a stored procedure definition

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a file with stored procedures defined that look like:

```
CREATE        PROCEDURE [XXXX].[procedure_name_here]
```

My regex so far is:

```
\.\[.*\]+.*
```

reference: http://rubular.com/r/Z0FiI78bqF

I need some help as it doesn't seem to be 100% correct.

Note: the [xxxx]. part may or may not be present (optional), but the word CREATE has to be there otherwise it would be another stored procedure calling a stored procedure, I'm just looking for the actual definition.

Answer (score 2):

If you can rely on the procedure name being between square brackets immediately after a dot, then you can write

```
\.\[(.*?)\]
```

the parentheses will capture the procedure name string for you.

If the dot is optional, or you need more verification that the line is a procedure definition, then use

```
CREATE\s+PROCEDURE\s+(?:\[.*?\]\.)?\[(.*?)\]
```

Answer (score -1):

SQL is not a regular language. That means it cannot correctly be parsed with a regular expression. It is certainly possible to write a correct parser for SQL, and it is certainly possible to write a correct parser for the subset of SQL that you care about. But it is not possible to do so with only a regular expression.

You can use regular expressions as a guess. But, depending on the choice of regular expression, you will get both false positives, where the regular expression says some text is valid SQL when it's not, and false negatives, where the regular expression says some text is invalid as SQL when it is actually perfectly valid.

So you are left with: either write a correct parser for SQL, or write a regular expression that makes a best guess - and make sure all your SQL files are written to pass that regular expression.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the scenario, I am not parsing sql for correctness, I am simply extracting certain stored procedure names that's all.